# Prove that $L_0 = (-i)^m \frac{d^m u}{dx^m}$ is a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, inner-products, spectral-theory

Here, the domain of $L_0$ is $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty} (a,b)$ (test functions on $(a,b)$). Also, $L_0$ is an operator in the $L_2 (a,b)$ space i.e. $L_0 : \ \mathcal{C}_0^{\infty} (a,b) \subset L_2 (a,b) \rightarrow L_2 (a,b)$

I already proved it for myself that $\langle L_0 u, u \rangle$ must be real-valued

But how on earth should I show that $L_0$ is positive? I know that if I take $u=0$, then $\langle L_0 u, u \rangle = 0$. But how can I find out, whether $\langle L_0 u, u \rangle > 0$ if I take $u \neq 0$?

Comment: $(-i)^m$ or $(-1)^m$?

Comment: @G.Gare $(-i)^m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $m$ is even, let $m=2n$ and it follows
$$\langle L_0u,u\rangle=(-1)^n\langle u,u^{(2n)}\rangle=(-1)^{2n}\langle u^{(n)},u^{(n)}\rangle=\|u^{(n)}\|^2\geq0.$$
This equals zero iff $u^{(n)}\equiv0$, which holds iff $u\equiv0$ since $u\in\mathcal C_0^\infty(a,b)$.

If $m$ is odd, there are counterexamples: Consider $L_0=(-i)u'$ on $\mathcal C_0^\infty(-1,1)$. Let $u$ be a real-valued test function in $\mathcal C_0^\infty(-1,1)$, for example,
$$u=e^{1/(x^2-1)}\ \text{if}\ x\in(-1,1),\quad u=0\ \text{otherwise},$$
then it follows
$$\langle L_0u,u\rangle=(-i)\int uu'=-\frac i2\int\big(u^2\big)'=-\frac i2\big(u^2(1)-u^2(-1)\big)=0,$$
but $u\neq0$ on $(-1,1)$. In general, let $m=2n+1$ and we have
$$\langle L_0u,u\rangle=(-i)\langle u^{(n)},u^{(n+1)}\rangle.$$
Since $\langle L_0u,u\rangle$ is real, $\langle u^{(n)},u^{(n+1)}\rangle$ is pure imaginary and therefore $0$ if $u$ is real-valued.

Comment: I see why for $m = 2n$ the operator is positive. But why is it positive for $m = 2n+1$? We only proved that the inner product will be equal to $0$ if $u = 0$. What I mean is: We can always take $A, B$ as some negative values, right? Which in effect could make our inner product be negative?

Comment: What I mean is why is it true that $\langle L_0 u, u \rangle = (-i)\langle u^{(n)}, u^{(n+1)} \rangle > 0$ for $u \neq 0$?

Comment: @user Thanks for the comment, and yes that's a very good point, let me update the answer!

Comment: @user Turns out that if $m$ is odd and $u$ is real-valued, then the inner product is always zero even if $u\neq0$. The details are in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you another question? How can I prove that the self-adjoint extension of $L_0$ is given by the operator $$A u = (-i)^m \frac{d^{2n} u}{dx^{2n}}$$ where the domain of $A$ consists of all $u \in W_2^m (a,b)$ such that $$u(a) = u'(a) = ... = u^{(m-1)}(a) = 0 \quad if \ a> - \infty$$ and $$u(b) = u'(b) = ... = u^{(m-1)}(b) = 0 \quad if \ b < + \infty$$ I thought about integrating by parts $\langle A u, u \rangle$ and show that these conditions must take place in order to cancel out the "not integrated component", but I don't know if it's correct, as $m \neq 2n$ here